# Redirect script of buy button

Tags: unity-game-engine

The buy button script don't redirect me to the next scene , what can I do ? What should I add to my code to make this possible

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PurchaseScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void BuyComplete(UnityEngine.Purchasing.Product product) 
    {       
        SceneManager.LoadScene("50");
    }

    public void BuyFailed(UnityEngine.Purchasing.Product product, UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchaseFailureReason fa)
    {
        Debug.Log("PURCHASE FAILED");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add some debugging to see if your "BuyComplete" method is being called.

Comment: Could you add more details of your setup and where this method is supposed to be called from?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `BuyCompleted` method its called when the buy have ended.

So your buy button should call another method that depending on its result it calls either `BuyComplete` or `BuyFailed`. Lets call that method `TryBuy`.

The button click is an `UnityEvent` called `onClick` to call a method when the button is clicked you need to add the method to the litseners of the event.

This can be made by code, but the easiest way is doing it in the inpector. Assuming you have done all of this.

You also need to add the new scene (in this case called "50") to the build. If you don't do that, you will never be able to open the scene.

To do this go to File/Build Settings/ an there you will see you main scene, to add other scenes I think you can drag and drop them there. The order is important, keep your main scene at the top.

Hope this could help.

Comment: To add the listener to the button (if you have the script in the same object the button is) just find in the inspector in the button section the event onClick and press in the + symbol. Then drag your object at the left side and in the right side find in the little menu your script name and click in the TryBuy method. Be sure this method is public.

Comment: I get this error : TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000025 (from typeref, class/assembly SimpleJson.SimpleJson, UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager.OnPurchaseSucceeded (System.String id, System.String receipt, System.String transactionId) (at /Users/stevenb/unity-src3/Extensions/UnityPurchasing/Runtime/Purchasing/PurchasingManager.cs:111)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.JSONStore.OnPurchaseSucceeded (System.String id, System.String receipt, System.String transactionID) (at <5089

Comment: Then I think the problem is not when loading the scene but in the code that makes the purchase.